# Put each tag on a new line when wrapping with Emmet in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, emmet

In PhpStorm 9.0 when wrapping a list of values, for example:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

With different abbreviations, for example:

```
p.$*
```

I have the input all in one line, like this:

```
<p class="1">Item 1</p><p class="2">Item 2</p><p class="3">Item 3</p>
```

How can I make tags appear on individual lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured that only inline elements are stacking in a single line. "p" tag has this behavior due to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LehkE.jpg) setting.

Answer (score 1):

Code is usually formatted according to specified code style settings when expanding Emmet abbreviations. If you like to have all tags placed on separate lines,  make sure to remove this tag from both 'Inline elements' and 'Don't break if inline contents' lists in `Settings/Editor/Code Style/HTML/Other`

Answer (score 0):

Also `faketag>p*` separate each line of `<p>`. And it's fast do delete `faketag` ater that.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences > Editor > Emmet > HTML > "Filters enabled by default": disable "Single line" option